# Trouble animating div height using CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to get a div to animate on load, scaling from 0px high to its full height. Here's the relevant CSS I have so far, developing in Chrome right now so I only have -webkit prefixes:

```
#teaserbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation-name: barAppear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes barAppear {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="teaserbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns clearfix">
      <p><a href="#jumper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet! &#8681;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having little success getting the animation to actually work--at first I thought it might be an issue scaling the height like that, but I've had no success animating the background color of the div either. If anybody thinks it might be helpful in solving my problem, I can provide the full anonymized source.

Any suggestions? I feel like I must be missing something fairly obvious, because I've had CSS animation working without a hitch in the past.

**Edit:** made a fiddle per Mr_Green's suggestion, available at http://jsfiddle.net/XYfE9/

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant: -webkit is no longer necessary. CSS3 was fully implemented for all Chromium browsers.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr_Green, added a link to a fiddle at the bottom.

Comment: Good point as well, @cygorx; -webkit is still necessary for older versions but really not needed for purposes of my testing.

Comment: I don't use CSS3 animations a lot but as it seems you cannot animate to 'auto', use a fixed height and it should work.

Comment: That does seem to be the issue, @Simon--not sure what was wrong before but I got animation with a fixed height to work now. I thought webkit had (against spec) implemented auto as an option for animation but that's not the case. My only concern is that the div will probably be a different height based on browser width, but that's a job for Javascript I suppose.

Comment: @cfqycwz: I added a couple Chrome-specific demos, for fixed height and dynamic height. If it's reasonable to add a container div, this should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, CSS animations don't appear to support using a height value of `auto`, with one solution being to use a fixed height instead.

If you need to support a dynamic height, you could measure the height with jQuery and then apply the measured height to the animation.

One possible way is to add a container around `#teaserbar`. Set the container to the measured height, and use start and end values of 0% and 100% for the animation. A quick test using 0% and 100% was successful, for an element in a fixed-height container. Not sure if this solution would present problems with the page layout, but there may be other ways to make use of the measured height that would not do so.

**Demos**    (targetting Webkit browsers only)

- [Fixed-height container](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/LPKce/2/)   (no jQuery)
- [Dynamic-height container](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/HmXH5/)   (uses jQuery)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="teaserbar">
        <p><a href="#jumper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet! &#8681;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes barAppear {
    from {
        height: 0%
    }
    to {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').height( $('#teaserbar').height() );
});
```